# What is the value of an ATM call under the Black Scholes Framework when $T \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: options, black-scholes

In the Black Scholes framework what is the value of an at-the-money vanilla European call option as time to maturity goes to infinit ($T \rightarrow \infty$)?

Comment: You should at the very least show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. We are not here to do you exercise sets.

Comment: @SRKK, I am sorry if it looks like i am asking you guys for solving my questions. I didnot get any ideas how to approach this one but when Gordon posted the answer i posted my thinking as well. I will keep this in min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Black-Scholes call option price is given by
\begin{align*}
C = S_0 N(d_+) - K e^{-rT}N(d_-),
\end{align*}
where $$d_{\pm}= \frac{\ln \frac{S_0}{K}+(r\pm\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2) T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.$$
Here, we assume that the interest rate $r\ge 0$ and $\sigma >0$.
For an at-the-money call option, that is, $K=S_0$, we note that
$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} d_+ = \infty$, that is, $$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} N(d_+) = 1.$$
In addition, if $r>0$, then $$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}Ke^{-rT} N(d_-) = 0,$$ and if $r =0$, then $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} d_- = -\infty$, and $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} N(d_-) = 0.$ Therefore, $$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} C = S_0.$$

Comment: only if r is less than one half sigma squared....

Comment: Thanks so much, If q>0, then would the value of the call option be 0?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but wouldnt  $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} e^{-qt} =  0$ and thus the value of the call option be zero

Comment: You may need to show your work. What is $q$ and how does it appear in Black-Scholes?